# Start Activity in same intent

Tags: android, android-intent

i want to know how to start all my activities in same intent. My app have a drawer activity and i want when i select any item, it will start an activity in the same intent, how can i do that ?

Main Acitivy

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class));
        return true;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "in the same intent"? Your terminologies seems mistaken. Only one Activity can be running at a point in time

Comment: In Google Drive app, you have an drawer with itens like "My Drive", "Google Photos", "Off-line". And when you select one of these lines it's start an diferent activity in same content. This is what i want to do here. This code is just a fragment from "MainAcitivy.java". This code show that when i click on "gallery" in my drawer, it will start another activity. Sorry my bad explanation and my bad english

Comment: @TonyStarkus nope, it's the same intent in google drive

Comment: So how can i do that ? Same intent for diferent itens in Drawer ?

Comment: You're searching for Fragments, not Intents. Again, terminology... Completely different concepts

Comment: Yes, sorry my mistake. Thank you !!!!

Answer (score 0):

I checked Google Drive and I'm guessing you're referring to the behavior that when you click on something only a part of the screen updates. You can easily implement this by using Fragments. I cannot explain it to you in detail but this is a developer.google link that will help you get started. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html

Comment: Yes, this is what i am looking for, but i did not know how to say xD Thanks man !! i will study this now. Thanks guys !!! Sorry my mistakes, i am noob